# Classical analogue of Heisenberg and Schrödinger pictures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

What do the Heisenberg and Schrödinger pictures in quantum mechanics correspond to in classical mechanics (if they correspond to anything)? It's kind of weird, because (if I understand it well) in classical mechanics the state of the system is determined by the dynamical variables positions and conjugate momenta, so the time dependence of the dynamical variables is the same as the time dependence of the state vector, I don't see whether the two could be separated. Nevertheless can it be done somehow?

Comment: ahh nice one and interesting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is really no analogue of the "pure state" or "state vector" in classical physics so there is no analogue of Schödinger's equation for ket vectors.

However, the density matrix has an analogue in classical physics, namely the probability distribution on the phase space, also called $\rho$. Of course, when we talk about it, we assume a statistical description i.e. we assume some ignorant about the classical system. The classical counterpart (and the classical limit!) of the "Schrödinger equation for the density matrix" is called [the Liouville equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)#Liouville_equations) or the equation from the Liouville's theorem, so that it's not confused with other things called the "Liouville equation".

The quantum counterpart of the usual dynamical equations from classical physics are of course the Heisenberg equations of motion, the equations describing the evolution in the Heisenberg picture. The classical equations of motion are literally the classical, $\hbar\to 0$, limit of the Heisenberg equations of motion.

I have oversimplified a bit. There is no classical counterpart of the wave function among the things that we normally learn about. However, there exists the Koopman-vonNeumann classical mechanics

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics

that is doing nothing else than to construct some "wave function"-based description of classical physics, including Born's rule.

Answer (score 5):

From [The Gateless Gate](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/glg/glg29.htm) by Mumon,

> Two monks were arguing about a flag. One said: "The flag is moving."
>
> The other said: "The wind is moving."
>
> The sixth patriarch happened to be passing by. He told them: "Not the
>   wind, not the flag; mind is moving."

The Heisenberg Picture is the the first monk, the Schroedinger picture is the second monk.

The approaches are mathematically equivalent, you have some state space manifold and you define some time flow along the manifold. The two pictures are dual to each other, like Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics (on the tangent and cotangent bundles respectively). Have a look at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/9807008.pdf) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: +1, and the Dirac/Interaction picture is the mind moving picture :)

Comment: @NikosM. I'm glad someone else thinks so. I used to include that whenever I gave the explanation, but then I started to wonder was I overstretching the analogy and so I'm holding off now until I can formulate a good justification.

Comment: Well, a nice synthesis of physics and zen, is always inspiring (at least to me) :). To the point, the answer (although in the context of zen) is similar to my answer (just replace a couple of words).

Comment: Plus, the referenced paper and the hamiltonian/lagrangian duality as pictures is nice as well

Answer (score 3):

The [already posted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/129269/44176) is, strictly speaking, correct; however i will try to provide an analogy of Heisenberg/Schrödinger pictures which can be classical.

The difference between the pictures is what part of the description carries the time dependence and evolution.

Heisenberg picture, has (the operators of) the observables carry the time-evolution while the state is not affected by time evolution.

In Schrödinger picture, the state carries the time evolution, while any operator-observables are not affected by it.

Now, consider a (single particle) classical system which is evolving in some frame of reference. One can assume a *picture* of the system where the frame of reference is static (lets say this is "*Heisenberg picture of the system*") and the particle observables (position/momentum) are evolving (wrt to the frame of ref). Or, on the other hand, say the system observables are static (wrt the frame of ref) while the frame itself is evolving (lets say this is "*Schrödinger picture of the system*"). This can be generalised to multiple particle systems, but is good for an analogy.

If one wants a closer analogy, one can assume a system which is liquid or gas and the frame of reference can be curvlinear. This will make a *probabilistic / density* description possible and is closer to a "quantum-like description"

Answer (score 1):

Measurable quantities are described by time evolution of observables classically. Think about this for a bit. In Classical Mechanics what we see evolving in time are quantities like momentum, position, etc, i.e **observable quantities**. This is why the Heisenberg picture is useful. Exactly the same expectation value is obtained when we leave the state ﬁxed as $|\psi(0)\rangle$ and allow the observable to evolve in time as $U(t)^†\hat{O}U(t)$ (Heisenberg picture) as opposed to the Schrodinger picture which is the state that evolves in time.

The equations of motion obtained from the Heisenberg picture look familiar from the equivalent ones in Classical Mechanics hence we can better demonstrate similarities (or differences) between QM and CM. Historically, the Heisenberg picture was developed (by Heisenberg) for his matrix mechanics formulation of quantum theory, and was developed in parallel to the wave-function formulation of quantum mechanics.

As for the Schrodinger picture, there is no classical analogue that I know of, and its one of the reasons that we shift constantly from picture to picture (Schrodinger, Heisenberg, Interaction pictures) when solving problems.

Comment: Can you tell me the classical analogue of the state vector?

Comment: @user3237992 There isn't one, as I have mentioned in my last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Not a general answer but an instance related to this is provided by the fluctuation dissipation theorem for time-dependent expectation values of an observable in statistical mechanics, close to equilibrium we have the relation

\begin{equation}
  \frac{\langle\theta_A\rangle_{neq}(t)-\langle\theta_A\rangle_{eq}}{\langle\theta_A\rangle_{neq}(0)-\langle\theta_A\rangle_{eq}}=\frac{\langle\theta_A(0)\theta_A(t)\rangle_{eq}-\langle\theta_A\rangle_{eq}^2}{\langle \theta_A^2\rangle_{eq}-\langle\theta_A\rangle_{eq}^2}
\end{equation}

here we are able to translate between a time-dependent distribution function $f(q_0,p_0,t)$ (Schrodinger)

$$
\langle\theta_A\rangle_{neq}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq_0 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp_0  \quad \theta(q_0,p_0) f(q_0,p_0,t)
$$

and a time-dependant observable (Heisenberg)

$$
\langle\theta_A(0)\theta_A(t)\rangle_{eq}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq_0 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp_0  \quad \theta(q_0,p_0)\theta(q(t),p(t)) e^{-H(q_0,p_0)/k_B T} 
$$

It would be interesting to know if one can do this more generally

Answer (score 0):

Here is my naive point of view:

### Schrodinger picture in QM

Remember that to solve a Quantum Mechanics problem we solve the Schrodinger equation
$$
i\hbar\dfrac{d}{dt}\Psi=\hat{H}\Psi \tag{1}
$$
with initial condition $f(x)$.

When we want **to observe** the system or make a prediction, at a desired time $t$, "we apply" a desired observable $\hat{Q}$ to $\Psi(x,t)$, obtaining the real value:
$$
Q(t)=\langle\Psi(x,t)|\hat{Q}|\Psi(x,t)\rangle. \tag{2}
$$
[image]

### Schrodinger picture in CM

To **compare this with Classical Mechanics**, for example a particle in a potential, you have to think of the "states" $s$ of the particle as living in an abstract set $S$ (something like the "Configurations of the Real World") and observables like "standardized procedures" to obtain a numerical value from a state. For example, the observable "position" $q$ would be a system of sticks or rods, independent of the state of the particle and independent of time, in the same way that $\hat{Q}$ is independent of $\Psi$ and $t$.
When we write $q(t)$ we indeed mean the composition of maps
$$
t \stackrel{s}{\mapsto} s(t) \stackrel{q}{\mapsto} q(s(t))
$$
Observe that these standard procedures are independent of time: we have established beforehand how are we going to take measures with our rods...

[image]

The key difference with QM is that in CM, the authentic state $s$ is not a mathematical object unlike the wavefunction $\Psi$ of QM. So in CM we are forced to write the differential equations in terms of the composed maps, instead of with the states itself.
But there is a trick. We usually assume the existence of observables that let us create a bijection between the set $S$ and a numerical set, for example $\mathbb R^2$ in the standard example of Hamiltonian mechanics:
$$
\begin{array}{rccc}
\varphi:& S &\to & \mathbb R^2\\
        & s &\mapsto & (q,p)
\end{array}
$$
So you identify the states $s$ with the pairs $s\equiv (q,p)$ and this way you can write differential equations directly for the states:
$$
\dot{s}=(X_H)_s \tag{3}
$$
with $X_H$ the corresponding Hamiltonian vector field. This would be Schrodinger equation (1).

And now, you have two distinguished observables $\pi_1,\pi_2$, the projections over the first and second coordinates. Indeed, all the "standardized procedures" get transformed under this identification into other "math operations" with $q$ and $p$. Now, you solve problems in a totally analogous  way to Schrodinger picture: evolve the state $s_0$ with the ODE above to a time $t$ and then use a observable (for example $q=\pi_1$) to obtain the prediction $Q(t)=\pi_1(s(t))$. So far, so good.

### Heisenberg picture in CM

The use (and abuse) we do of $q(t):=q(s(t)), p(t):=p(s(t)),...$ makes us think that observables $q,p,...$ are other kind of entities. They are considered maps associating a numerical value to a time $t$ together with an initial condition $C$, and satisfying some differential equations.

[image]

Observables constitute a commutative c-star algebra.

And we have that the evolution of one of them is given by the equation
$$
\frac{d}{dt} q(t)=\{q,H\} \tag{4}
$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian and $\{.,.\}$ the Poisson bracket.

### Heisenberg picture in QM

This different approach to observables like smooth functions let us think of them as elements of an algebra, which is commutative. For different reasons (see [Why did physics go quantum](https://ajpancollantes.github.io/%E2%98%95REFLECTIONS/Why%20did%20physics%20go%20quantum.md.html)) we suspect that the algebra of observables should be a noncommutative c-star algebra. So instead of time dependent functions of the state space, we take time dependent operators in the wavefunction space.

[image]

These operators, once they are known, are waiting for us to provided a time $t$ and an initial condition $f$ to yield a value, as before.

Mathematically, the relation between Schrodinger and Heisenberg picture comes as follows. A formal solution of equation (1) is
$$
\Psi=e^{-i \frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}t}f,
$$
indeed this is nothing but other way to write (1).
Now, for every observable $\hat{Q}$ we define the time-dependent operator
$$
\tilde{Q}(t)=e^{i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}t} \hat{Q} e^{-i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}t}.
$$
In order to make predictions it is clear that (2) is substituted by
$$
Q(t)=\langle f |\tilde{Q}(t)| f \rangle. \tag{5}
$$
Observe that $\tilde{Q}$ satisfies
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\tilde{Q}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}[\tilde{Q},\hat{H}], \tag{6}
$$
since
$$
\frac{d\tilde{Q}}{dt} = i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar} e^{i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}t} \hat{Q} e^{-i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}t} - e^{i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}t} \hat{Q} i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar} e^{-i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}t}.
$$
and since $e^{-i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}t}$ commutes with $\hat{H}$
$$
\frac{d\tilde{Q}}{dt} = i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar} \tilde{Q} - \tilde{Q} i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}[\tilde{Q},\hat{H}]
$$
as desired.
Observe that equation (6) correspond to equation (4).